# Pushes the object on the axes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem that I can not solve. I have an object, and I want when I click somewhere near him to move with some force. something like the picture below.

[image]

I'd even want some idea!!!
Help!!!

```
    public float speed;
public GameObject player;
Vector3 target;
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        var mouseClick = Input.mousePosition;
        mouseClick.z = player.transform.position.z - Camera.main.transform.position.z;
        target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mouseClick);

        var distanceToTarget = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, target);

        if (distanceToTarget > 2)
        {
            target.z = 0;
            player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(target * speed);
        }
        else
            print("travelling COMPLETE");
    }
}
```

Comment: With a little use of math and physics, you can achieve this. First get the clicked position (Point A). You know the objects "center" position (Point B). Subtract 2 points and get a vector. That will be the vector of the force you will apply to the object.

Comment: I tried to use physics to AddForce the object.

Comment: if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(transform.right * speed);
        }

Comment: but it is clear that it only gives you strength in one direction

Comment: Vector3 worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

Comment: so the first time I did this and that's why I do not know

Comment: Thank you for updating the post.

Comment: this code goes, but not at all

Comment: it comes to the position of the mouse, and it stops

Comment: You want it to move away from the mouse?  (That is what your image shows)

Comment: yes, as in the picture

Comment: how to play football with the ball. when I click somewhere this to go in the opposite direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code you provided in your answer...

```
public float speed;
public GameObject player;
Vector3 directionVector;

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        // Input.mousePosition is already in pixel coordinates so the z should already be 0.
        Vector3 mouseWorldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        // Now that the mouse is a world position lets set his z to the same as the player
        mouseWorldPosition.z = player.transform.position.z;
        // Gives us a direction from the mouse to the player.  So think of it as Player <- Mouse remove the < and you have the equation
        directionVector = player.transform.position - mouseWorldPosition;
    }
    else
    {
        directionVector = Vector3.zero;
    }
}

// Physics based movement should be done in FixedUpdate
private void FixedUpdate()
{
        player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(directionVector.normalized * speed);
}
```

Comment: @AnghelinaGuznac if this solved your problem feel free to mark it as the answer so other people with a similar problem can find it.  If you have any other issues please make a new question, with an in-depth explanation of the issue and what you tried.  Have a good day.